# How remove an image and its details from a multiple image uploader?and how reduced the number of items uploaded?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I try to build a multiple image uploader.In it image uploading is work properly and its progress bar is working correctly..but it's close button is not working.If i click the close button the image and details are removed from the file..but it also uploaded and showed in progres bar.. how can i maintain this problem? can anyone help me??pls...
my demo is http://demo.enfintech.net/MultipleFileUpload/
my code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()" xmlns:aaronhardy="aaronhardy.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";


        global
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import aaronhardy.ProgressBar;

            import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
            import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
            import flash.utils.setTimeout;

            import mx.charts.renderers.AreaRenderer;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.Request;
            import mx.geom.RoundedRectangle;
            import mx.utils.OnDemandEventDispatcher;
                private var refAddFiles:FileReferenceList=new FileReferenceList;
                private var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference;
                private var serverSideUrl:String="http://demo.enfintech.net/MultipleFileUpload/fileUploader/uploadFile.php";
                //                      private var serverSideUrl:String="http://192.168.1.60/fileUploader/uploadFile.php";
                private var list:Array=new Array();
                public var urlReq:URLRequest;
                private var initial:int=0;
                private var totalSize:Number=0;
                private var isSelected:Boolean=false;
                private var images:Object;
                private var fileSizeArray:Array=new Array();
                private var temp:Number=0;
                public var fileListLength:int;
                public var loaded:int;
                public var totalUploaded:int;
                [Bindable]  private var files:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            private function init():void
            {
                Security.loadPolicyFile("http://demo.enfintech.net/crossdomain.xml");
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                refAddFiles.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,fileRefSelect);
                urlReq = new URLRequest(serverSideUrl);
            }

            private function fileRefSelect(event:Event):void
            {
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                upload1();
                isSelected=true;
            }
            private function uploadFiles():void
            {
                if(files.length==0)

                {
                    Alert.show("Please Select file(s)");
                }
                else
                {
                    gotoMultipleUpload();
                }
            }


            public function gotoMultipleUpload():void
            {
//              var fileReference:FileReference;
                fileReference = FileReference(list[initial]);
                fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadCompleteHandler);
                fileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressBarEvent);
                fileReference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,uploadFails);
                fileReference.upload(urlReq);
            }

            private function uploadFails(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Error");
            }
            private function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                totalUploaded=totalUploaded+list[initial].size;
                if(initial<fileListLength-1)
                {
                    initial++;
                    gotoMultipleUpload();

                }
                else
                {
                    progressBar2.label="Upload Completed ("+(initial+1)+"/"+fileListLength+")";
                    Alert.show("File Uploaded Completed");
                    upload0.enabled=false;
                    cancel.enabled=false;
                    select.enabled=true;
                }
            }

            private function progressBarEvent(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {

                files[initial].currentValue=event.bytesLoaded;
                progressBar2.visible=true;
                var numPerc:Number=Math.round(((event.bytesLoaded+totalUploaded)/totalSize)*100);
                progressBar2.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded+totalUploaded,totalSize);
                progressBar2.label="Uploading "+numPerc+"% ("+(initial+1)+"/"+fileListLength+")";
            }

            public function upload1():void
            {
                try
                {
                initial=0;
                loaded=0;
                totalUploaded=0;
                list=new Array();
                list=refAddFiles.fileList;
                fileListLength=list.length;
                fileSizeArray.push(list[0].size);
                for(var i:int=0;i<fileListLength;i++)
                {
                    totalSize+=list[i].size;
                    list[i].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRefCompleted);
                    list[i].load();
                }
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    Alert.show(e.message);
                }
            }   

            public function fileRefCompleted(event:Event):void
            {
                loaded=loaded+1;
                if(loaded==fileListLength)
                addFilesToDatagrid();
            }
            public function addFilesToDatagrid():void
            {
                var temp:Number;
                for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++)
                {
                    images=new Object();
                    images["fileName"]=list[i].name;
                    images["size"]=list[i].size;
                    images["preview"]=list[i].data as ByteArray;
                    images["currentValue"]=0;


                    if(list[i].size/1024>=1)
                    {
                        temp=list[i].size/1024;
                        if(temp/1024>=1)
                        {
                            temp=temp/1024;
                            images["sizeconverted"]=String(temp.toFixed(1))+"Mb";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            images["sizeconverted"]=String(temp.toFixed(1))+"Kb";
                        }
                    }
                    files.addItem(images);

                }
                select.enabled=false;
            }
            public function removeItem():void
            {
                var item:int=dgMain.selectedIndex;
                files.removeItemAt(item);

            }
            private function cancelClick():void
            {
                fileReference.cancel();
                progressBar2.label="FileUpload Cancelled";
                upload0.enabled=true;
            }

            private function browsebtn():void
            {
                files.removeAll();
                files.refresh();
                var arr:Array = [];
                arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
                refAddFiles.browse(arr);
                upload0.enabled=true;
                cancel.enabled=true;
                totalUploaded=0;
                totalSize=0;

            }

            private function titleWindowClose():void
            {
                var item:int=dgMain.selectedIndex;
                files.removeAll();
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                select.enabled=true;
                upload0.enabled=true;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TitleWindow x="204" y="10" width="520" height="325" id="titleWindow"
                   skinClass="TitleSkin" title="File Uploader" close="titleWindowClose()">
        <mx:DataGrid id="dgMain" x="0" y="0" width="518" height="237" allowMultipleSelection="true"
                     dataProvider="{files}" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" headerHeight="0"
                     horizontalScrollPolicy="off" variableRowHeight="true">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="preview" headerText="Preview" width="40" paddingLeft="5" itemRenderer="ImageDatagrdItmRndr"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fileName" headerText="Name" width="380" itemRenderer="itmRndrPrgrsBar"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="sizeconverted" headerText="Size" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn id="close" headerText="Size" width="40" itemRenderer="buttonClose"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar2" x="-1" y="237" width="518" barColor="haloblue"            
                        labelPlacement="center" mode="manual" themeColor="#eaeaea"
                        trackColors="[white,halosilver]"/>
        <s:Button id="select" bottom="5" width="87" height="30" label="Select files"
                  click="browsebtn()" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="-91" skinClass="Skin.setButtonSkin"
                  />
        <s:Button id="upload0" bottom="5" width="79" height="30" label="Upload" click="uploadFiles()"
                  fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="0" skinClass="Skin.setButtonSkin"/>
        <s:Button id="cancel" bottom="5" width="79" height="30" label="Cancel" fontFamily="Arial" click="cancelClick()"
                  fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="91" skinClass="Skin.setButtonSkin"/>

    </s:TitleWindow>
    <s:Label id="tet" color="red" x="468" y="394" width="130"/>
    <s:Label id="tet2" x="236" y="394" width="93" color="red"/>
</s:Application>
```

and the item render for close button is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          focusEnabled="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Image horizontalCenter="0"  source="dialog-close.png"
             verticalCenter="0"  click="FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeItem();"/>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: - i have removed some skins and renderer as it was showing error, Please find modified code below, i have changes some logic to make it bit work :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()" xmlns:aaronhardy="aaronhardy.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";


        global
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
            import flash.utils.flash_proxy;
            import flash.utils.setTimeout;

            import mx.charts.renderers.AreaRenderer;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.Request;
            import mx.geom.RoundedRectangle;
            import mx.utils.OnDemandEventDispatcher;
            private var refAddFiles:FileReferenceList=new FileReferenceList;
            private var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference;
            private var serverSideUrl:String="http://demo.enfintech.net/MultipleFileUpload/fileUploader/uploadFile.php";
            //                      private var serverSideUrl:String="http://192.168.1.60/fileUploader/uploadFile.php";
            [Bindable]
            private var list:Array=new Array();
            public var urlReq:URLRequest;
            private var initial:int=0;

            [Bindable]
            private var totalSize:Number=0;
            private var isSelected:Boolean=false;
            private var images:Object;
            private var fileSizeArray:Array=new Array();
            private var temp:Number=0;

            [Bindable]
            public var fileListLength:int;
            public var loaded:int;
            public var totalUploaded:int;
            [Bindable]  private var files:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            private function init():void
            {
                Security.loadPolicyFile("http://demo.enfintech.net/crossdomain.xml");
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                refAddFiles.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,fileRefSelect);
                urlReq = new URLRequest(serverSideUrl);
            }

            private function fileRefSelect(event:Event):void
            {
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                upload1();
                isSelected=true;
            }
            private function uploadFiles():void
            {
                if(files.length==0)

                {
                    Alert.show("Please Select file(s)");
                }
                else
                {
                    gotoMultipleUpload();
                }
            }


            public function gotoMultipleUpload():void
            {
                //              var fileReference:FileReference;
                fileReference = FileReference(list[initial]);
                fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadCompleteHandler);
                fileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressBarEvent);
                fileReference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,uploadFails);
                fileReference.upload(urlReq);
            }

            private function uploadFails(event:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Error");
            }
            private function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                totalUploaded=totalUploaded+list[initial].size;

                files.refresh();

                if(initial<fileListLength-1)
                {
                    initial++;
                    gotoMultipleUpload();

                }
                else
                {
                    progressBar2.label="Upload Completed ("+(initial+1)+"/"+fileListLength+")";
                    Alert.show("File Uploaded Completed");
                    upload0.enabled=false;
                    cancel.enabled=false;
                    select.enabled=true;
                }
            }

            private function progressBarEvent(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {

                files[initial].currentValue=event.bytesLoaded;
                progressBar2.visible=true;
                var numPerc:Number=Math.round(((event.bytesLoaded+totalUploaded)/totalSize)*100);
                progressBar2.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded+totalUploaded,totalSize);
                progressBar2.label="Uploading "+numPerc+"% ("+(initial+1)+"/"+fileListLength+")";
            }

            public function upload1():void
            {
                try
                {
                    initial=0;
                    loaded=0;
                    totalUploaded=0;
                    list=new Array();
                    list=refAddFiles.fileList;
                    fileListLength=list.length;
                    fileSizeArray.push(list[0].size);
                    for(var i:int=0;i<fileListLength;i++)
                    {
                        totalSize+=list[i].size;
                        list[i].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRefCompleted);
                        list[i].load();
                    }
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    Alert.show(e.message);
                }
            }   

            public function fileRefCompleted(event:Event):void
            {
                loaded=loaded+1;
                if(loaded==fileListLength)
                    addFilesToDatagrid();
            }
            public function addFilesToDatagrid():void
            {
                var temp:Number;
                for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++)
                {
                    images=new Object();
                    images["fileName"]=list[i].name;
                    images["size"]=list[i].size;
                    images["preview"]=list[i].data as ByteArray;
                    images["currentValue"]=0;


                    if(list[i].size/1024>=1)
                    {
                        temp=list[i].size/1024;
                        if(temp/1024>=1)
                        {
                            temp=temp/1024;
                            images["sizeconverted"]=String(temp.toFixed(1))+"Mb";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            images["sizeconverted"]=String(temp.toFixed(1))+"Kb";
                        }
                    }
                    files.addItem(images);

                }
                select.enabled=false;
            }
            public function removeItem(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var item:int=dgMain.selectedIndex;
                files.getItemAt(item)
                totalSize -= files.getItemAt(item).size;
                files.removeItemAt(item);
                fileListLength = list.length = files.length;

            }
            private function cancelClick():void
            {
                fileReference.cancel();
                progressBar2.label="FileUpload Cancelled";
                upload0.enabled=true;
            }

            private function browsebtn():void
            {
                files.removeAll();
                files.refresh();
                var arr:Array = [];
                arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
                refAddFiles.browse(arr);
                upload0.enabled=true;
                cancel.enabled=true;
                totalUploaded=0;
                totalSize=0;

            }

            private function titleWindowClose():void
            {
                var item:int=dgMain.selectedIndex;
                files.removeAll();
                progressBar2.visible=false;
                select.enabled=true;
                upload0.enabled=true;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TitleWindow x="204" y="10" width="520" height="325" id="titleWindow"
                   title="File Uploader" close="titleWindowClose()">
        <mx:DataGrid id="dgMain" x="0" y="0" width="518" height="237" allowMultipleSelection="true"
                     dataProvider="{files}" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" headerHeight="0"
                     horizontalScrollPolicy="off" variableRowHeight="true">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="preview" headerText="Preview" width="40" paddingLeft="5"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fileName" headerText="Name" width="380"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="sizeconverted" headerText="Size" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn id="close" headerText="Size" width="40" itemRenderer="buttonClose"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar2" x="-1" y="237" width="518"             
                        labelPlacement="center" mode="manual" 
                        />
        <s:Button id="select" bottom="5" width="87" height="30" label="Select files"
                  click="browsebtn()" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="-91"
                  />
        <s:Button id="upload0" bottom="5" width="79" height="30" label="Upload" click="uploadFiles()"
                  fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="0" />
        <s:Button id="cancel" bottom="5" width="79" height="30" label="Cancel" fontFamily="Arial" click="cancelClick()"
                  fontSize="12" horizontalCenter="91" />

    </s:TitleWindow>
    <s:Label id="tet" color="red" x="468" y="394" width="130"/>
    <s:Label id="tet2" x="236" y="394" width="93" color="red"/>
</s:Application>
```

**buttonClose.mxml**: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          focusEnabled="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                if(value.currentValue >0)
                    closeImage.visible = false;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Image id="closeImage" horizontalCenter="0"  source="dialog-close.png"
              verticalCenter="0"  click="FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeItem(event);"/>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Hope this may help you...

Comment: sorry mahesh............ it's not working properly.I think the size of each image 'totalUpload' is not changed after removing the item.(during the uploading files the progress bar value exceed 100 sometimes and sometimes the item render progress bar is not loaded fully)..Could you please fix this problem??